# Trying to run a file in python, but there is an error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a login to run a program, but when I try to run the file at the end of the program it throws an error

```
while True:
        login1 = input("Login:")
        login2 = input("Password:")
        file = open(login1+".txt", "r")
        data   = file.readline()
        file.close()
        if data == login1+":"+login2:
            print("Welcome")
            exec(open(r"E:\Coding\Python AI project").read())
            break
        print("Incorrect username or password.")
```

I expected it to run the file but it throws the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Coding/login.py", line 27, in <module>
    exec(open(r"E:\Coding\Python AI project").read())
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'E:\\Coding\\Python AI project'
```

Comment: I would highly recommend *against* using `exec` on file contents. Is `E:` a remote drive that you have read permissions on? Also, is `Python AI Project` a file or directory?

Comment: You are looking for the `subprocess` module if `Python AI project` is a script to run. You can basically ignore the fact that Python has an `exec` function and never actually miss it.

Comment: C.Nivs Python AI Project is a file and E: is a drive I have read/write privileges on